# Experiment design advice

Tags: regression, experiment-design

I’d like to understand a good experiment design for the following example:

Say sales people are trying to find the ideal time (in days) to send a follow up phone call to increase conversion (a sale).

I’d want to test a bunch of different times and structure the analysis as a regression.

What sort of experiment design should I use to have all of those different experiment arms? Let’s say [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] days are the times of interest.

Would a factorial design be appropriate to randomize users into each experiment arm (where each experiment arm is a group receiving a follow up call after [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or 10] days)?  Or is there a better experiment design to use?

If it’s properly randomized do I have to worry about controlling for factors such as gender, age, etc?

Comment: You experiment design is OK.  The problem you are going to having is collecting enough data in order to make a reasonable prediction.  Your outcome is binary, does the follow-up phone make a conversion? Yes or No.  You will need dozens and dozens follow-ups for each day in order to have a reason confidences in a conversion rate for each day.  You may want to simplify you treatment from 10 days to a short and long delay, to minimize your data requirements

Comment: @Dave2e: That looks like an answer, can you make it one?